# Selenium WebDriver - Click HOME Key

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am at the bottom of page, now I want to scroll up to the top of the page directly (as the page may be very long and scrolled down to the bottom) by clicking Home Key. For this I have tried something like  this which is offcourse not working -

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.keyDown(Keys.HOME).build().perform();
```

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Are you trying to scroll to the top of the page?

Comment: @Manali - Thanx for the help. Using JSE we can achieve this, is there a way we can press HOME key using selenium ?

Comment: Use Robot class to simulate a keypress and keyrelease event. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below functions:

```
void scrollToBottom(WebDriver driver)
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
    }

void scrollToTop(WebDriver driver)
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0));");
    }

void scrollToMiddle(WebDriver driver)
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight/2,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight/2));");
    }
```

And Scroll element into view:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Press HOME Key:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily *Scroll Up* or *Down* by using *JavascriptExecutor*.

Before you use *JavascriptExecutor*, import it in your test code as below.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Now create one instance of *WebDriver* interface as below,(Assuming your Test-browser is *Firefox* )

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

**Scroll Down:**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)"); //y value '250' can be altered
```

**Scroll up:**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)"); //x value '250' can be altered
```

Also for more information on scrolling please click [here](http://rupeshrshinde.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-perform-scroll-operation-in.html)